# LUKS/Cryptsetup possibly corrupted after hard shutdown

Tags: 20.04, encryption, luks, initramfs, cryptsetup

My laptop is a a Dell Precision 5560 running Ubuntu 20.04.3. It has LUKS disk encryption set up on it.

About a week ago, it completely froze (I'm not sure why) such that my only recourse to get it working again was to do a hard shut down, i.e. by holding down the power button for 10 seconds. After I did this, it seems to have corrupted something, because now when I boot, it momentarily shows the following error:

```
cryptsetup: Bad password or options?
```

and after a few seconds this changes to:

```
cryptsetup: ERROR; system: maximum number of tries exceeded
```

After a further 30 seconds or so, it drops me into `initramfs`. If I type `exit` here it shows a few error messages, notably `ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!`.

---

Thankfully, I was able to workaround this by doing the following:

> `echo -e '#!/usr/bin/sh\n/usr/bin/tpm2_nvread 0x1500016' > /clientbuild/scripts/tpm2-getkey`
>
> Run `/clientbuild/scripts/tpm2-getkey` manually and make note of the password.
>
> Open the luks volume, rescan lvm volumes, and continue the scripts that failed to run:
>
> `/clientbuild/scripts/tpm2-getkey | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 ubuntu-p3`
>
> `lvm lvscan`
>
> `sh /scripts/local`
>
> Press ctrl+D to return control to the initramfs.

At this point I'm then prompted to enter the password that I noted down, which I do, and then I can boot into my system successfully.

**However, every time I reboot my machine, I have to complete the above steps again. So what's been corrupted here, and how do I repair it permanently?**

Comment: I don't have an answer. I suggest you boot from an installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. Copy your personal files into a second external drive. Reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd like to avoid it :-) But I may just have to if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not certain of what's going on, but it might help to entirely rebuild your Grub.

Please start by fully updating your system.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If there are errors, repair them.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then rebuild Grub.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -ck all
```

Reboot to see if this helps. Sorry if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your TPM was cleared to install a BIOS or TPM update? Either manually or via `fwupd`? You can `grep fwupd /var/log/syslog` to get more info.

This article makes it clear that the firmware must be cleared to update TPM firmware:
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-au/000184894/how-to-successfully-update-the-tpm-firmware-on-your-dell-computer